# can I add custom metrics do bluemix graphite

Tags: ibm-cloud, kubernetes

I'm testing the bluemix container service. Since IBM provides a grafana/graphite for my account to collect cpu/mem stats on all of my containers, i naturally want to add my own statistics.

Is it possible to report custom stats form the kubernetes cluster or from inside my containers to the ibm graphite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the documentation you can/have-to use the coreOS prometheus-operator to provide a prometheus in your cluster and then add a prometheus datasource to grafana.

afaik you can not add the prometheus datasource to the metric.ng.bluemix.net grafana

WARNING: the current version of the linked coreOS repository is for kubernetes 1.6 (bluemix runs 1.5). You have to get an old version of the scripts used by coreOS